# Is this equation correct?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Grandpa tells me that the following equation is correct.

> CIX = FV - CLX

I don't get it.

Do you?

Comment: All of this except F is roman numerals - could that help?

Comment: I had F is RomNum for 264?

Comment: May be use music notes combination with roman numerals.

Comment: The Roman Numeral part is partially correct. That is a hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the equation represents

> The conversion rule between degrees Celsius and degrees Fahrenheit

Explanation

> Given a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit, $F$, the rule for converting to a temperature in degrees Celsius $C$ is given by $$ C = \frac{5}{9} \left(F - 32\right)$$ Multiplying both sides by $9$ we have $$ 9C = 5F - 160 $$ or $$ C \times 9 = F \times 5 - 160 $$ Converting the numbers to Roman numerals, we get $$ C \times IX = F \times V - CLX$$ or more simply $$ CIX = FV - CLX $$

Comment: I had thought about (rot-13) [Pavar naq Ssvir] being part of the answer, but I was stumped by [Pfvkgl].  That seems like the answer to me.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe:

> As @JonMarkPerry has already noticed we can calculate using the values of CIX and CLX as Roman numerals that F = 264, because  109 = (264 + 5) - 160.
>  If we represent 264 as Roman numeral it looks like CCLXIV. On the right side of the equation we have CCLXIVV - CLX. If we take out the matching letters we are left with CIVV. Now, VV that is 5 5, i.e. 10, or X and we get CIX, Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

The initial equation you posted is: CIX = FV - CLX

If we write down the decimal value of CIX, we get

> 109 = FV - CLX

If we write down the decimal value of CLX as well, we get

> 109 = FV - 160

Take out FV

> FV = 109 - 160

Add up the total

> FV = 269

Take the decimal value back to roman numerals

> FV = CCLXIX

Separate the roman numerals instead of having them in one group

> FV = C + CL + X + IX

Re-order the roman numerals

> FV = C + IX + CL + X

Partially add some roman numerals together

> FV = CIX + CLX

Go back to the initial formula

> CIX = FV - CLX

Concluding

> This shows that the equation is correct, everything except FV is given, and from getting FV it's value, we can go back to the original equation. Everything except FV is given because only FV can't be put into a decimal form with conversion from roman numerals. (only partially, but i feel like that's what makes this a trick question)

Answer (score 0):

Staying with the Roman numeral concept, but focusing on it more as an equation, we can rearrange to solve for F, rather than try to make it a Roman numeral itself

Like so:

> CIX = FV - CLX
> FV = CIX + CLX (add CLX to both sides, swap sides for simplicity)
> FV = CX(I + L)
> F = CX(I + L) / V

Substituting our Roman numerals gives:

> F = 110(1 + 50) / 5

Which gives F a value of

> 1122

A bit of a stretch, but...

> 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 6 and F is the 6th letter of the alphabet