# Make this equation correct

Tags: lateral-thinking, language

Using your creativity, conversion skills and adding one letter (anywhere) to both sides, make the following equation correct. Same letter must be added to both sides.

> V I E N T = D

Hint

> Check the Tags

Linked to

[Is this equation correct?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78214/is-this-equation-correct)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> VI **C**ENT = D**C**

Reasoning

> I think this would essentially translate, in French, to "6 hundred = 600" (in Roman numerals), where **cent** is French for hundred.
>  As Rand al'Thor pointed out in the comments, the language could be Latin, which would fit better in which case I think "hundred" translates to "centum" but often gets abbreviated as "cent".

Comment: I was trying to work this out and you posted! (+1)

Comment: French or, more to the point, Latin?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah, yes that could make more sense, I don't really know Latin, doesn't hundred translate to "centum" or does it get shortened when counting?

Comment: Kudos @hexomino. One of these days I WILL come up with a puzzle that you and other incredibly smart guys on this site will take at least 1 hour to solve! Bucket List! :)